# Php неправильно кодирует кириллические символы

Tags: php

Отправляю данные их пхп на `rest-api`. Запрос идёт корректно, но сами параметры неправильно кодируются.
На стороне rest-api я вижу кириллические символы вот таким образом `('fname', 'Ð\x9fÐµÑ\x82Ñ\x80Ð¾')`. Подскажите где я ошибся

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit');

$curl = curl_init();
$url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 2);
 $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $url[0];

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
   CURLOPT_URL => 'xxx:8080/insert_zayavka?token=token2&subid='.$_POST['subid'].'&fname='.$_POST['f_name'].'&sname='.$_POST['l_name'].'&patr=&email='.$_POST['email'].'&ph$

  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
));



$response = curl_exec($curl);



curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли про [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.urlencode.php)

```
'xxx:8080/insert_zayavka?token=token2&subid='.urlencode($_POST['subid']).'...';
```